# Why do we have to AllowAnonymous in identity framework .NET when creating new user (ApplicationUser)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

When I create new user, using userManager create function of identity framework, it does not work (throw exception) because it does not call onModelCreating of the identity Context. 
While if I allAnonymous on the controller class, it works fine.

Now the creating new user will throw exception that tenant_id is not nullable in my db tenant_id is going somehow null. But when I allowAnonymous on the controller of this service it creates user.
Code:

```
                    var currentThread = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as CustomPrincipal;
                    var dataBaseConnection = currentThread.TenantInfo.DbConnection;
                    var dbConnection = dataBaseConnection.GetSqlConnForDbName();
                    var context = new IdentityContext(dbConnection, true);
                    var userStore = new ApplicationUserStore(context);
                    var _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore) { PasswordHasher = new PasswordHashHelper() };


                    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
                    {
                        UserName = userModel.UserName,
                        Tenant_ID = 1,
                    };
                    _userManager.Create(user);
```

Comment: You should provide relevant parts of your source code, the stack trace and an actual question. A [mcve] is also welcome.

Comment: Do you have any Authorization Policy enabled? Also.. what is the .NET framework version?

Comment: sure i put some code and more explanation.